# LVM can't see external USB drive

Tags: usb, lvm

I am trying to add an external USB drive to my Ubuntu 14.04 LVM volume. Using the Logical Volume Management GUI, I clicked the extend volume button, but my USB drive does not appear in the list. It is a 4TB drive formatted as ext4.

Answer (score 2):

You need to format the volume for lvm and import it into your volume group.  Assuming the partition in question is /dev/sdb1 and your volume group is named vg:

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb1
sudo vgextend vg /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: volume group context and explanation would be appreciated.  Excellent answer.